# Start MS-Edge from command with save-as enabled

Tags: microsoft-edge

After some search with no success, I'm posting this simple question here.

I have a web application that can run without a Web-Server (just one HTML and one JS files). When running in this mode, I need to make sure that the SAVE-AS option is always available. My guess is that such behavior can be achieved using the appropriate switch (as part of the command line).

So, my question is: Does such switch exist? If not, Is there an alternative way to launch MS-Edge from command line forcing the browser to present the SAVE-AS option when a file is downloaded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such a switch for the SAVE-AS option, but I do have an alternative for you:

You can enable [PromptForDownloadLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#promptfordownloadlocation) policy, so that Edge is forced to prepare a SAVE-AS option for every download.

Comment: Thanks Kendrick for your response. I guess this is a modification within the registry, right? If so, it is not a feasible solution for what I need. My application is a stand-alone such that I copy few files into, say, a memory stick, hand it to you, you plug it into your computer and run a small bat file that launches Edge with a reference to a HTML file plus flags that disable CORS. No Web server needed at all. Though possible (update registry) this is something that I cannot include in the solution.

Comment: @FDavidov Yea right, you need to modify the registry or group policy template to enable this policy. The download preference is something that should be edited from the browser settings, not programmatically. However, you may try to request such a switch by sending feedback to Edge Dev Team (Alt+Shift+I).